# Вызвать Lua функцию из таблицы Lua через lua C Api

Tags: c++, lua

У меня есть следующий код на Lua:

```
main_ds = {};
main_ds.teg={};
main_ds.teg:Size = function () return 5; end;
```

Я пытаюсь из плюсов достучаться до этой функции (демонстрационный пример, но структура та же) :

```
lua_settop(L,0);
lua_getglobal(L,"main_ds");
lua_getfield(L,-1,"teg");
lua_getfield(L,-1,"Size");

lua_remove(L,-3);
lua_remove(L,-2);
lua_call(L,0,1); // должен вернуть 5
```

Однако у меня не получается это сделать, всегда получаю нуль в качестве результата. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем тут может быть загвоздка.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в вопросе, код на Lua нерабочий. Должно быть вот так:

```
-- объявление функции
main_ds.teg.Size = function(self) 
    return 5 
end

-- вызов
print(main_ds.teg:Size()) -- что на самом деле: main_ds.teg.Size(teg)
```

После этого исправления ваш Си-код должен начать работать и в результате на стеке будет "5".

Если хотите использовать `self` внутри функции на Lua (обычно это надо), то перед вызовом функции на стек нужно положить таблицу `teg`:

```
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);

int err = luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
if (err) {
   printf("Cannot dofile: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
   lua_pop(L, 1);
   return 1;
}    

lua_getglobal(L, "main_ds");        
lua_getfield(L, -1, "teg");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Size");

lua_pushvalue(L, -2); // параметр "self" = таблица "teg"

if(lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0) != 0) {
    printf("Func call failed: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return 1;
}    

int ret = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 3);

printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
```

---

Как выяснилось из комментариев, код на Lua написан топикстартером от балды и на самом деле таблицы создаются в Си. И, очевидно, создаются они неправильно, поэтому вот вдогонку пример, как можно создать глобальную таблицу, внутри неё вложенную таблицу, внутри которой есть функция:

```
lua_createtable(L,0,0); // main_ds
lua_createtable(L,0,0); // teg
lua_pushcfunction(L, size_func);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "Size"); // set teg.Size
lua_setfield(L, -2, "teg"); // set main_ds.teg
lua_setglobal(L, "main_ds");
```

Вызываемая функция:

```
int size_func(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_pushnumber(L, 5);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Нет, там дело не в коде Луа (этот код я не проверяя написал в качестве примера.)
Если нужен исходный вариант, то вот он:
http://luaq.ru/CreateDataSource.html

Я делаю обертку для этих функций. Делаю следующим образом:
1) В плюсах вызываю функцию CreateDataSource, затем заношу результат в поле teg глобальной переменной main_ds. 

Сама форма вызова функции из луа будет следующей:
main_ds.teg:Size(). 

Данные заносятся правильно (проверял уже) но вот получить доступ к методу Size который находится в таблице teg которая является полем в глобальной main_ds, у меня не получается...

Comment: Вот отрывок кода которым я инициализирую таблицу и пытаюсь вызвать искомую функцию:
https://paste.ofcode.org/zXp4EtjWQhKTq9Yi4Qay6d

Comment: @AndreyKrivcov Там дело не в вызове функции, вызывается она правильно. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @AndreyKrivcov И на будущее: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: пример как раз и был задан. (и он был минимальным. все что далее скидывал, это вам для конкретики).

Сама таблица создается 100% правильно и луа код тоже верен.

Comment: @AndreyKrivcov У вас в вопросе код на Lua не работает. Запустите Lua и убедитесь в этом сами. После того как вы исправите код на луа, ваш пример Си кода начинает работать и как итог - проблема не воспроизводится. Так что советую задать вопрос с кодом, который воспроизводит проблему. Глядишь, при написании такого кода вы и баг в своём основном коде самостоятельно обнаружите.

Comment: Я пишу только обертку для луа. Луа код пишет компания разрабатывающая терминал Квик. Их код работает (если его в луа вызывать) соответственно он верен. Однако мой вызыв в плюсах не работает... Ладно, благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @AndreyKrivcov Проблема в том, что вы в основном коде пишите так же как и в примерах - без проверки на ошибки. Поэтому вам и приходится гадать почему не работает (и где конкретно оно не работает). Как только у вас дойдут руки написать код по человечески, со всеми проверками результатов вызова луа функций, вы тут же обнаружите точку отказа. Обработка ошибок - наше всё.

Comment: так вызывается он без ошибок. (однако возвращается 0 в качестве ответа) Можно конечно считать что это не 0 (как цифра) а nil но смысла это не меняет, код не крошится.

Comment: @AndreyKrivcov А код и не должен "крошится". Вы же общаетесь с Си API, а значит надо проверять коды возврата **каждой** сишной функции. У вас этого и близко нету, отсюда и мучения.